# Process to change artifactory filestore from S3 to NFS

Tags: artifactory

I am looking at moving my filestore from S3 to NFS. I am not sure what that process would be. Has anyone had to do this? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

There is no outside-of-the-box solution to move your artifacts from S3 to NFS.
With that being said, I would recommend looking at third-party tools (i.e [RSync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)).

Regardless, it is important **after** moving/copying the binaries to validate the filestore integrity with Artifactory's DB. This can be done using this [JFrog Filestore Integrity plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/filestore/filestoreIntegrity).

I hope this information helps you.